CSS styling is not applied, or disappear after being applied
The text color and background do not change. On other projects, everything fell off altogether
Updating the F5 page and CTRL + F5 does not help. When running Open live server in VS code, it shows that the changes are applied first, and then disappear.
This is my head:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

This is my body:


* {
  font-family: "Comfortaa", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

html,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #5c5959;
}

body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>My site</h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="col-8">
        <ul>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-home'></i><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-bowl-hot'></i><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
          <li>
            <i class='bx bxs-user'></i><a href="#">Кабинет</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Админ панель</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Выход</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-phone'></i><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>




Your styles are being overridden by Bootstrap.
In devtools you can see the Bootstrap rule (above) overriding your rule (below).

The specificity is the same, so this is a order of precedence issue as result of importing your own CSS file above Bootstrap's.
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My blog</title>
    <!-- Importing our custom styles here --><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Importing bootstrap here --><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

Moving your own styles to the bottom should resolve the issue. CSS rules are applied first to last, overriding same or lower specificity. Like asking "hey paint the wall green", "actually, yellow"
If we remove the external resources you can see the styles are now being applied:


* {
  font-family: "Comfortaa", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

html,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #5c5959;
}

body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>My site</h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="col-8">
        <ul>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-home'></i><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-bowl-hot'></i><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
          <li>
            <i class='bx bxs-user'></i><a href="#">Кабинет</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Админ панель</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Выход</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><i class='bx bxs-phone'></i><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



